# Windows 7: Right click on file and run custom Excel VBA script

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I wrote a macro in Excel VBA that can scrape files with an .f06 extension for certain data and then creates a spreadsheet that summarizes the data.

It is inconvenient to have to find the Excel workbook, open it, run the macro, & select the .f06 file to generate this summary.

I prefer to right-click on the .f06 file directly and have an option called 'scrape' that I could select and then it would run the code automatically.

1) Is this possible?

2) Can I use the existing macro-enabled Excel spreadsheet as the referenced code?  Or do I need to re-write it in another language?

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 if relevant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but if you're on a company computer, I doubt that you'll be able to do some of the required steps.

1) write a VBScript for your macro according to the following guide:

http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/run-macro-without-opening-excel-using-vbscript/

2) Launch the VBS you wrote in Step 1 from the right click menu, according to the following guide:

http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Launch-vbs-from-the-rightclick-menu-advanced-m32062.aspx

Best of luck!

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the relevant information from your links? That way it will still be helpful to others if your links die.